# Allowing one user to update another in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've just dusted off an old project in rails 2.3.14 and I'm trying to add a little bit of functionality.

I have an application that manages lending transactions between parties.  User A "Lender" has the ability to send a message to User B "Borrower" to remind them that their loan is overdue.

When User A sends this message, I want to lock User B's account by means of changing a boolean value "account_locked" in their record on the database.

At the moment this is what I have (pared to relevant bits):

Lender edits loan to status "overdue"

**Loans Controller:**

```
    def update
        case @loan.status
            when "overdue"
              do_magic.send #sends overdue mail just fine
              @loan.borrower.lock_account
        end
    end
```

**User Model:**

```
  def lock_account
    self.account_locked = true
    self.save
  end
```

I don't get any error or output, but the record remains unchanged.  Where am I going wrong?   (Something more specific than "everywhere" would be appreciated!!).  I'm not sure if it's just plain wrong or if there's some security issue that isolates records from each other.

Comment: It's probably encountering an error when trying to save the record. Try changing `self.save` to `self.save!`, that will output any errors it has while trying to save the record to the console.

Comment: Yes, that was it!  It was silently failing a validates_format_of in my user model.  I just #'ed that out and it works perfectly.  Thank you kindly.